# How to choose between one-way, two-anova and multliple regression?

Tags: r, regression, anova, modeling

I am working on the data set that consists of Patients' id (after stroke), Time (they can walk after going through the program), the Program they follow and the Visit number when the Time was measured.

```
Patient   Program   Time(walking)   Visit(Check)
1           P1       12             Day 10
2           P3       23             Day 5
3           P3       8              Day 1
4           P2       36             Day 10
5           P1       10             Day 1
6           P2       86             Day 10
6           P1       13             Day 5
```

I am investigating whether **there is evidence that the effects of different programs differ over time?**

**My approach** was to consider the ANOVA test for the response variable Time (effect) and the Independent variable Program. In such a way:

```
new <- aov(Time~Programme, dane)
> summary(new)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Programme    2  398.4   199.2    0.61   0.58
Residuals    5 1633.5   326.7
```

But I am hesitant now about the fact that maybe the **Visit column should be somehow included** in this investigation?. Shall I use a different method to come up with an answer to that question **(ex. regression? two-way ANOVA?)**

Comment: Is this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576193/how-to-determine-how-much-variation-was-due-to-the-differences-between-a-group  also your Q? Then  Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find 
information on how to do this in the **My Account** 
section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.